# getting a network related or instance specific when trying to connect to localhost

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect to localhost and I am getting this error:

`a network related or instance specific when trying to connect to localhost`

I have Management Studio installed and I noticed that the SQL Server Agent is not showing up in Services.

I have reinstalled Management Studio to no avail.

Does anyone know what is cause?

Comment: It looks like you do not have SQL Server installed. SSMS is just a client tool used to connect to SQL Server, locally or remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, SSMS is a CLIENT TOOL, and just because you installed it, does NOT mean there is a localhost Sql **Server** installed.

Check your "windows services" for

[image]

After/IF you find a windows service with "SQL Server" prefix, it will show that instance name.

So for the image above, my connection string would be;

```
localhost\SQLEXPRESS2012
```

or

```
localhost\SQLEXPRESS2017
```

Possibly you have a default (no (non) instance name)... which means there would be nothing in the () (in the screen shot).  Then (and only then) would the connection string be:

```
localhost
```

If you do not have the windows service(s), you can install Sql Server (Express? or other edition).  Below link is an example of a hundred different "how to intall sql server" articles.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5528/installing-sql-server-2017-express/